# Thread 1: EXC_BreakPoint

Tags: xcode

My Application run in `Xcode 4.3`.
But crashed in `xcode 5.0.2`.
This is image of crashed.

```
/Users/rakesh/Documents/Crash Error.tiff
```

How to solve this crashed..

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: you should give a lot more information so someone is able to help you. use the debugger and show us the log and the crash reason together with some relevant code.

Comment: i cannot add image due to minimum 10 reputation..

Comment: I don't understand how this question was upvoted.  It contains no information at all to help solve the issue; if you cannot upload an image then provide the stacktrace text (which is better anyway).  The fact that you provide the name of the screenshot on your local filesystem is laughable.

Comment: trap    Thread 1:EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xe7ffdefe)